# Combining two facts via a boolean OR in Gnu Prolog

Tags: prolog, boolean-expression, gnu-prolog

I'm totally new to Prolog. So please excuse this possibly extermely simple qiuestion: I have a few facts like

```
likes(peter,cars).
likes(maria,bikes).
likes(walter,bikes).
likes(paul,bikes).
likes(paul,cars).
```

in a file `likes.pl`. Now I'm trying to check whether `paul` likes `cars` ***and*** `bikes`, so I tried on GNU Prolog's REPL:

```
| ? - [likes].
| ? - likes(paul,bikes) #\/ likes(paul,cars).
```

but I get "uncaught exception:...". Obviously I'm doing something wrong. - How can I combine two facts with an AND in GNU Prolog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator you are using `#\/` is a Boolean Finite Domain operator used in constraint programming `clp(b)`.

If you just want a conjunction of two facts A and B, use `A, B`. If you want a disjunction of them use `A; B`.

In your case you can just type `likes(paul, bikes), likes(paul, cars).`.

Comment: Thanks @rajashekar, works perfectly! I guess I have to read up on _Finite Domain operators_ and _constraint programming_...

Comment: @halloleo : The inputs to the boolean fd operators must be evaluable to `0` or  `1`. So if you give it `X #/\ Y` it returns `X = 1, Y = 1`.  It works with any propositional formula. CLP is powerful, but I suggest you go there after becoming more familiar with core prolog itself.